# Constructing a set of variables

Tags: netlogo

I have a question about Netlogo.  I have two breeds of turtles, breed1 and breed2.  Breed2 has a variable called theta.  First, a random number of breed1 turtles change to breed2; the breed2 then theta set at random.  Later, another random number of breed1 become breed2, who will also have theta set at random.

My two questions are:

1.) How can I ensure that only those turtles that change their breed in the second round of breed-changing set their theta variable? I don't want those that changed in the first round to lose the theta variable that was set for them immediately after changing.

2.) Is there a way I can construct a set of all the theta variables that have been set so far? I want my breed2 to later on make decisions based on the maximum value of theta that has been set so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask two separate questions separately, but ...

1. There are many ways to do this. Example 1: If you always update to a nonzero value of theta, just test for a zero and only change a zero.  Example 2: add a `can-change-theta` attribute to breed2 and always initialize it to true but change it to false after resetting `theta`.  Example 3: gather your new `breed2s` into an agentset (or a list, if necessary) and change theta only for these turtles.
2. If you really want the max, you don't need all values.  Just add a global variable `max-theta` and update it each time you update a `theta`.  If you really want all, add a `thetas` global and initialize it as an empty list; append to this list each time you update a `theta` attribute, and use `max` to pull out the max whenever you wish.